# How to make photo fill column size (Bootstrap)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

As title says, I want image to fill column size, here is the photo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBGrm.png

I tried with adding img-responsive but it doesn't work or I did it wrong.

Comment: there are padding and margin added to the column. You might have to remove it to occupy complete space. inspect the element and look for the css rules that adds padding and margin and overwrite it..

Comment: "fill" as in you don't want to keep the aspect ratio of the image?

Comment: This image is just to test displaying post.

Comment: It did n't actually, my column html syntax was wrong..

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your `image` size is too small, So you have 2 options for achieving what you want

**1:** Just use high resolution image and apply `img-responsive` class to `img` tag.

**2:** Or apply `width:100%` and `height:auto` to `img` tag, but in this case your image will be blurred.

```css
.myImg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="myImg" />
  </div>
</div>
```